# Multiconditional, dictionary-based, count in Excel 2019

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel coding gurus, can someone help me count in Excel? :) I need a count, based on multiple, dictionaty depandant, conditions.

**What I have**:
I have an Excel 2019. Not the 365 edition.
I have an Excel sheet called, say **Dicts** with a table of 2 columns. I is a dictionary. Column `I` contains list of people. And each person in the `I` column has the country of his/her origin denoted in the correspondent cell of `H` column.

For a better view check this picture, plz.

[image: Dictionary of persons with their Country of Origin]

And I have a DataSheet, that contains records of various persons from the dictionary table along wiht some data on each record.
For a better view check this picture, plz.

[image]

**Now, the question is**:
How can I count the number of all the citizens of USA and Iitaly in the column `A` that have either **Y** or **M** in the correspondent cell of Column `B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following in Office 365:

```
=LET(condition1,FILTER(A2:A25,MMULT(--({"Y","M"}=B2:B25),SEQUENCE(2,,1,0))),
     condition2,FILTER(Table1[C2],MMULT(--({"USA","Irtaly"}=Table1[C1]),SEQUENCE(2,,1,0))),
SUM(--(TRANSPOSE(condition1)=condition2)))
```

In Excel 2019 you could use the following:

```
=SUM(
     --(TRANSPOSE(INDEX(Table1[C2],
                        AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Table1[C1])-1/(MMULT((--(Table1[C1]={"USA","Irtaly"})),ROW(1:2)^0)),
                        ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,SUMPRODUCT(--({"USA","Irtaly"}=Table1[C1])))))))
        =INDEX(A2:A25,
               AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A2:A25)-1/(MMULT((--(B2:B25={"Y","M"})),ROW(1:2)^0)),
               ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,SUMPRODUCT(--({"Y","M"}=B2:B25))))))))
```

In Excel versions prior to Office 365 this formula needs to be entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`

Change the Table name and references to your needs (I can't reproduce the characters used and Table Name is nowhere mentioned)

When using different system language using different separators use the following:

```
=SUM(
     --(TRANSPOSE(INDEX(Table1[Стовпець2];
                        AGGREGATE(15;6;ROW(Table1[Стовпець1])-1/(MMULT((--(Table1[Стовпець1]={"USA"\"Irtaly"}));ROW(1:2)^0));
                        ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A;SUMPRODUCT(--({"USA"\"Irtaly"}=Table1[Стовпець1])))))))
        =INDEX(A2:A25;
               AGGREGATE(15;6;ROW(A2:A25)-1/(MMULT((--(B2:B25={"Y"\"M"}));ROW(1:2)^0));
               ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A;SUMPRODUCT(--({"Y"\"M"}=B2:B25))))))))
```

Comment: be aware the question specifies a non-O365 version, `LET` function is from [2021](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/functions/updates-2021-new-functions.htm), and the formula, in this case, will be more verbose because of that limitation, maybe not too much for your approach I was thinking in a different way and it will produce a large solution because of that

Comment: Good point. Even that it was obviously stated in both the title and question I must've been blind to it. I'll check for a solution that's usable in an earlier Excel later today.

Comment: Per my understanding not just `LET`, but other functions can't be used such as `FILTER`, `UNIQUE` so it makes it very hard.

Comment: True; FILTER can be replaced by INDEX/AGGREGATE, UNIQUE by FREQUENCY/MATCH and SEQUENCE by ROW. See edit for a version that should work in Excel 2019.

Comment: I didn't know the trick to get an array or 1's via `ROW(1:2)^0` that is really smart.

Comment: Yeah and the ROW/INDEX/SUMRPODUCT-part is a replacement for SEQUENCE.

Comment: @P.b. Sorry I've tried Your solution for Excel 2019 ... yet somehow the formula can't be saved in a cell as it reports an error. I did had Table1[C1/2] substitued for Tab_1[Стовпець1/2] but with no awail.
And I'm currently pretty much outta brainpower to play with it more ... Gotta get some rest. I used to be Oracle pl/sql-er before I was summoned to Ukrainian army. Now, playing with Excel is my attempt to help my mates to get their stockpiling/reporting more automated. I do hope that this coming week I'll have some time to toy around your solution and make it work.

Comment: `=SUM(     --(TRANSPOSE(INDEX(Tab_1[Стовпець2],                        AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Tab_1[Стовпець1])-1/(MMULT((--(Tab_1[Стовпець1]={"USA","Irtaly"})),ROW(1:2)^0)),                        ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,SUMPRODUCT(--({"USA","Irtaly"}=Tab_1[Стовпець1])))))))        =INDEX(A2:A25,               AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A2:A25)-1/(MMULT((--(B2:B25={"Y","M"})),ROW(1:2)^0)),               ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,SUMPRODUCT(--({"Y","M"}=B2:B25))))))))` entered with `ctrl+shift+enter` should work. What is the error you receive?

Comment: That's the general error.</br>

`There's a problem with this formula.

Not trying to type a formula?

When the first character is equal (=) or minus (-) sign, Excel thinks it's a formula: `
That kind of stuff.

Comment: Ha! In my case parameter separator should be `;` instead of `,`.  :)
So now Excel does parse the formula. But gives another error: `#N/A` (_A value is not avaliable for the formula or function_)

Comment: Alright. Separators in the formula are different than inside the arrays when using different system language. Try separator `\ ` inside each array. Like `{"word1"\"word2"}`

Comment: I also edited my answer

Comment: @P.b , Well, now it returns 0. Though it should return at least 4...

Comment: You used ctrl + shift + enter entering the formula?

Comment: Yup. BTW, it returns zero regardless of usage "ctrl + shift + enter" or just a bare "enter".

Comment: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AhxknrNHLDPC7RZZ1UDtQnUZReNS

Comment: I shared the file and it should automatically open in your language settings that way.

Comment: @P.b , I have to admit that the solution does work in the Google Docs' Excel (while it is opened online). Thank you 4 sharing hte file.  Yet it still produces 0 in my local excel. I have saved the file you've shared to my laptop and ... the formula stopped working. It shows that same zero. And yes, saving process did formatted the formula to my local settings.

Comment: I have no explanation for that, sorry

Comment: Yup. Thank you for all your effort. I'll mark the answer as a correct as it does work in your file.

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine you're looking for something simpler, but what about this (pseudocode, based on `COUNTIFS()` worksheet function):

```
=COUNT_Multiple_Criteria(range,country="USA", done="Y") + 
 COUNT_Multiple_Criteria(range,country="USA", done="M") + 
 COUNT_Multiple_Criteria(range,country="Italy", done="Y") +
 COUNT_Multiple_Criteria(range,country="Italy", done="M")
```

Comment: That doesn't work (at least in my case) as there is no COUNT_Multiple_Criteria function in it. Maybe that's an additional hand-crafted function that you have in your VBA part of Excel. But I do hope to avoid macrosing as it will scare away those that will use this solution.

Comment: @TatoRo: I've edited my answer, mentioning I've written my answer in pseudocode: it's the idea to replace `COUNT_Multiple_Criteria()` by `COUNTIFS()`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try the following approach. In cell: `H4` put the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
  N(ISNUMBER(MATCH(INDEX(A3:A8, MATCH(D3:D7, B3:B8,0)), H2:I2,0))),
  N(ISNUMBER(MATCH(E3:E7,H3:I3,0)))
)
```

Here is the output:
[image: sample output file]

The formula uses valid functions for Excel 2019, but that is not enough, you need to validate the expected behavior. After [dynamic array behavior](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-vs-legacy-cse-array-formulas-ca421f1b-fbb2-4c99-9924-df571bd4f1b4) was introduced for most of the functions the output should be different. In such cases you can try the legacy approach: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to ensure a dynamic array output.

If that doesn't work then an alternative is to use `MMULT` as follow, assuming `IF` returns a dynamic array for your Excel version:

```
=SUM(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(IF(INDEX(A3:A8, MATCH(D3:D7,B3:B8,0))=H2:I2,1,0)), 
  IF(E3:E7=H3:I3,1,0)))
```

that `SUM` per country all names with `Y` or `M`.

### Explanation

Let's use the `LET` function for better understanding:

```
=LET(lkUpC, H2:I2, lkupD, H3:J3, countries, INDEX(A3:A8, MATCH(D3:D7, B3:B8,0)),
  cCnts, N(ISNUMBER(MATCH(countries, lkUpC,0))),
  dCnts, N(ISNUMBER(MATCH(E3:E7,lkupD,0))),
  SUMPRODUCT(cCnts, dCnts)
)
```

The name `countries` finds the corresponding countries for the **Dataset** columns. The name `cCnts` returns an array with the same number of rows as `countries` having `1` for `LkUpC` match values otherwise `0`. Similarly `dCnts` the Done counts based on `lkUpD`. Both arrays have the same size, so we can invoke `SUMPRODUCT` to count the number of items that satisfy both conditions (columns `D` and `E` are highlighted in yellow in the above screenshot)

Comment: I've tried this approach and it didn't work in my Excel even with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` - it returns `#VALUE!` error.

Comment: The second array of SUMPRODUCT (`N(ISNUMBER(MATCH(E3:E7,H3:I3,0)))`) composes itself just fine as far as I see.

Comment: But I do not see how the 1s array assembles itself ... 
`=SUM(
  N(ISNUMBER(MATCH(INDEX(A3:A8; MATCH(D3:D7; B3:B8;0)); H2:I2;0)));
  )` produces zero.

Comment: Try to do it step by step, to identify where is the issue. I don't have your version, so I cannot test exact the same. For example: `=MATCH(D3:D7, B3:B8,0)` returns `{1;2;3;5;6}`, i.e. `5x1` array. Then `=INDEX(A3:A8, MATCH(D3:D7, B3:B8,0))` returns: `{Canada;USA;USA;Ireland;Irtaly}` and finally the outer `MATCH` returns: `{#N/A;1;1;#N/A;2}`. Try to check this first please. Keep in mine my formula doesn't use `SUM`, instead `SUMPRODUCT`. They are equivalent for new versions, but I don't know for older

Comment: @TatoRo I added in my answer a solution using `MMULT`, try if this works.

Comment: Somehow the `MMULT` solution doesn't work as well. I'm still trying to wrap my head around why the total solution returns `#VALUE!` To be more exact - I just can't figure out why the heck `=IF(INDEX(A3:A11;MATCH(D4;B3:B11;0))={"USA"\"Irtaly"};1;0)` returns 1 (and that is correct), but `=IF(INDEX(A3:A11;MATCH(D7;B3:B11;0))={"USA"\"Irtaly"};1;0)` returns 0. Somehow it seems that IF can't compare with the second element of an arry.

Comment: Moreover: `=IF("USA"=H2:I2;1;0)` returns 1, yet `=IF("Irtaly"=H2:I2;1;0)` returns 0. Hence the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

1. The `table` in `sheet` `Dicts` is named `loPeople` with fields: `Country` and `People`
2. The data in `sheet` `DataSheet` is located in a table named `loDone` with fields: `Name` and `Done`

Try this formula:

```
= SUM( IFERROR( IF(
 MATCH( loDone[Done], {"M","Y"}, 0 )
 * MATCH( INDEX( loPeople[Country],
 MATCH( loDone[Name], loPeople[People], 0 ) ), {"Ctry.C","Ctry.E"}, 0 ),
 1 ), 0 ) )
```

[image]

*Dynamic Formula*: If a dynamic formula is required, let's assume that:

1. The Country criteria is located in a table*{a}* named: `loSelCtry`
2. The Done criteria is located in table*{a}* named: `loSelDone`

Try this formula:

```
= SUM( IFERROR( IF(
 MATCH( loDone[Done], loSelDone, 0 ) *
 MATCH( INDEX( loPeople[Country],
 MATCH( loDone[Name], loPeople[People], 0 ) ), loSelCtry, 0 ),
 1 ), 0 ) )
```

[image]
*{a}*Using tables for the criteria enhances the dynamics of the formula.*